# java.net.UnknownServiceException when using Google Maps Java API

Tags: java, google-maps, okhttp

I'm trying to access Google Maps from my Java code as follows:

```
GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext.Builder().apiKey("API_KEY_HERE").build();
//Setting variables...
DistanceMatrix matrix = DistanceMatrixApi.newRequest(context).origins(origins).destinations(destinations).await();
```

Calling await() throws an exception:

```
java.net.UnknownServiceException: Unable to find acceptable protocols. isFallback=false, modes=[ConnectionSpec(cipherSuites=[TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA], tlsVersions=[TLS_1_3, TLS_1_2], supportsTlsExtensions=true), ConnectionSpec()], supported protocols=[TLSv1]
```

I gather this is coming from the OkHttp library used by Google Maps and that it has something to do with the TLS version, but I have no idea what to do to address it. All of the test cases in the source code use a mock web server and there are no examples of specifying a real server, leading me to believe that it was done under the hood.

Does anyone have example code for using the Google Maps Java API with a real web server?

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Comment: My JVM (from System.getProperty("java.version")) is 1.8.0_221.

Answer (score 2):

Your JVM isn't configured to use a new-enough version of TLS.

```
supported protocols=[TLSv1]
```

Make sure your JVM is 8 or newer and up-to-date. Also make sure any custom security providers (bouncycastle) are up to date.

Comment: My JVM (from System.getProperty("java.version")) is 1.8.0_221. I have not been able to find anything that might be overriding this. jdk.tls.client.protocols is null, which I understand should default Java 8 to TLS 1.2.

Is there another way to check what's affecting the choice of TLS versions?

Comment: Does it connect okay in a test case, or a main method with no other libraries? Looks like something is changing defaults on you.

Comment: I"ve confirmed that the minimal example works in a new project in the same Eclipse workspace.

Comment: (The exact same code fails with the TLS error in the existing project.)

Comment: Furthermore, if I manually create an SSLSocket and call getEnabledProtocols(), I see TLS 1, 1.1, and 1.2. Something is affecting specifically the protocols visible to the Google Maps code.

Answer (score 0):

This error is might be because of the version of okhttp3 library try to use different version of okhttp3.